# C# Linq to Entites, take take 1st Entity from set of Entities with same Date

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a table that looks like:
Key Date ... Name ... Status ...
**(ID) May** ...
(ID) May ...
(ID) May ...
**(ID) June** ...
(ID) June ...
(ID) June ...
**(ID) Jul** ...
(ID) Jul ...

What I need is to take the entities in bold as that is the overall property for the set.
So it looks like:

(ID) May ...
(ID) June ...
(ID) Jul ...

The Entity Set is retrieved with:

```
var status = from a in ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
                     where a.InspectionID == new Guid(inspID)
                     && a.DateTaken > before
                     && a.DateTaken <= DateTime.Now
                     orderby a.DateTaken descending, a.Status descending
                     select a;
```

Now i just need to filter out the ones I don't want.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492.aspx) as well as a call to [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535183.aspx).

For example, given your original query, `status`, you can do:

```
var firstStatuses = 
    status.GroupBy(i => i.DateTaken).Select(g => g.First());
```

Note that LINQ-to-Entities might not be able to properly group the data, based on requirements for the select clause in your underlying database.

With that, you can always call [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) to force the query to occur on objects in memory:

```
var firstStatuses = 
    status.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.DateTaken).Select(g => g.First());
```

One caveat, you should probably order each group depending on which item you want to be returned (if they aren't already ordered correctly).

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly when I used `.AsQueryable()` instead of the `.AsEnumerable()` - the method is in my DomainService class and I wanted an IQueryable returned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `group by` clause...

```
var status = from a in ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
             where a.InspectionID == new Guid(inspID)
             && a.DateTaken > before
             && a.DateTaken <= DateTime.Now
             group a by a.DateTaken.Month into g
             from m in g
             select new 
             {
               g.Key, g.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken).First()
             };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an IEqualityComparer that only looks at the DateTaken field, and then use Distinct() like this:

```
public class DateTakenComparer : IEqualityComparer<InspectionReading>
{
    public bool Equals(InspectionReading x, InspectionReading y)
    {
        return x.DateTaken == y.DateTaken;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(InspectionReading obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var statuses = ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
    .Distinct(new DateTakenComparer())
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I love this method. Unfortunately it threw up an error which I couldn't solve so I had to go with the other solution as I managed to get that to work. Thank you though, it never occurred to me to use an IEqualityComparer.